# How can View Component be used to call PartialView by its name instead of loading default.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I wanted to load Partial Views based upon TopUserCount value which is received by argument. I have different PartialViews available to suffice this requirement. But seems View Component only loads Default.cshtml

something like this:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int TopUserCount)
{
    var items = GetUsers().OrderByDescending(u => u.Points).Take(TopUserCount);
    if(TopUserCount == 1) return View("customView1");
    if (TopUserCount == 2) return View("customView2");
    else
        return View(items);  //defaultView.cshtml
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to place the partial views at right folder structure.
in this case under 'Views\ControllerName\Components\ViewComponentName'

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement seems funky; i would suggest using a `case` statement like this:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int TopUserCount)
{
    var items = GetUsers().OrderByDescending(u => u.Points).Take(TopUserCount);
    switch(TopUserCount)
    {
    case 1:
        return View("customView1");
        break; 
    case 2:
        return View("customView2");
        break;
    default:
        return View(items);  //defaultView.cshtml
        break;                   
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch statement is pretty much the same in this case. With increasing number of views the cognitive complexity of the switch approach could increase more than recommended. For this, a dictionary mapping could be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int TopUserCount)
{
            var items = GetUsers().OrderByDescending(u => u.Points).Take(TopUserCount);

            if (TopUserCount == 1) return View("customView1", items); 
            else if (TopUserCount == 2) return View("customView2", items); 
            else return View("defaultView", items);        

}
```

I switched your second if to else if; or you should use case statement, am not going to change much here, however your file structure has to look like

Views/Shared/Components/{ComponentName}/Default.cshtml
Views/{ControllerName}/Components/{ComponentName}/Default.cshtml